# как создать цикл удаляющий символы из строки по очереди,пока не закончиться сама строка

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, циклы

```
def remove_char(s):
    return s[1 : -1]
s="legalays"
print (remove_char(s))
```

нужно чтобы удаляло первый и последний символ пока строка не станет пустой

Answer (score 2):

пустая строка приводится к False, поэтому цикл можно организовать таким образом

```
def remove_char(s):
    return s[1 : -1]


s="legalays"
while s:
    s = remove_char(s)
    print (s)
```

результат

```
egalay
gala
al
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = 'some long text'
print(text)
for i in range(int(len(text) / 2)):
    text = text[1:-1]
    print(text)

# some long text
# ome long tex
# me long te
# e long t
#  long
# long
# on
#
```

Comment: `int(len(text) / 2)` вернёт не то же самое, что и `len(text) // 2`?